# Run React dev server inside another application

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, webpack-dev-server

In our old .jsp application, we are integrating react.

My react dev server is running on http://localhost:3000 and existing application at http://localhost:8100.

I included all the required js & CSS files of reacting into JSP page. which is working fine.

When when I'm using lazy-loading in React, for ex:

```
import('some-file.js').then(file => {
   // Some work
});
```

In this case Webpack is trying to load chunk from localhost:8100 instead of Dev server.

I'm using **react-script** for development and build.

[image]

Comment: could please try to add in module.exports { output:{publicPath: ' 
  "http://localhost:3000/static/js/dist/ or http:/http://0.0.0.0:3000/dist/"'} } in webpack.config.js file and check whether it works or not???

Comment: Its http:/locallhost:3000/dist in the above comment

Comment: did above thing works??

Comment: Thanks SAI for quick reply. Let me verify.

Comment: Thanks PALLAMOLLA SAI, your Idea works. I fixed it by setting publicPath: "http:localhost:3000".

Answer (score 2):

Try to add **publicPath** like below in webconfig.js files.

```
output: {
        //
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/static/js/dist' or
        // publicPath : 'http://localhost:3000/dist'
    }
```